# How to signal other users with JavaScript in real time every time a change has been made?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web-applications

I want to make some real time action with JavaScript, so all users could be signaled from the changes in the web-app in real time. I use PHP to store the information that is changed, and which must be displayed for all the users whenever it is changed.

I have tried using a PHP page that checks if data has changed, and then JavaScript refreshes it every 100ms, but I noticed that is overkill.

How can I achieve these real time updates without overwhelming my PHP script with useless requests?

Comment: `websockets` - there is a great solution `node.js` with `socket.io` http://socket.io

Comment: You can also look into Server Sent Events / EventSource which is supported in HTML5 - to do that you'll need to use an asynchronous server such as node.js rather than PHP, otherwise you'll end up with infinite loops checking database tables for new records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) is tool what you are looking for - according to Alaa websocket suggestion. It makes things done really quick, works in modern browsers and is easy to learn.

I've found it like 2 months ago, ant till now commited two projects with core functionalities using this lib.

Answer (score 1):

use websocket messages to push the action from the server to the client and read it on the client side in Java Script this link helped 
http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

Comment: [socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) will make it quick. Faced same problem few weeks ago.

Comment: @Rookie Especially for you tested in on adroid 4.1.3, kernel 2.6.32, standard (most troublesome) android browser on Xperia Mini from 2011y, and chat demo works. And in case of that phone its extraordinary that something works on it, so you have great chance to success with sockets ;)

Comment: @yergo, may you post that socket.io as an asnwer, so i can accept it? I really liked it.